# Dependencies of Hangfire client code at Hangfire Server while executing the job fetched from db

Tags: .net, mongodb, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, hangfire

I am using Hangfire to trigger a task daily. I have made two solutions. One for Hangfire Client and another for Hangfire Server. The task is to make a call to another API. When I run this Hangfire client, it is adding the job to MongoDB Successfully.

But when Server solution is ran, It is throwing an error :
Could not load file or assembly 'schedulingclient.Web, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=93cadf9107ebec2e'. The system cannot find the file specified.

scheduling client is the API and also works as Hangfire client. This dependencies are throwing errors when Server is trying to execute the parsed job. 
The job which is in Client has no 'usings' related to the other files in solution. though I am facing this issue. I have tried referencing the client's .dll in Server's solution. It is working but this is not the ideal way as client is an API not a library. Please let me know if there are any mistakes and any suggestions, Welcome.

Comment: You need to put the common code in a library which will be referenced by both server and client code